# Angular Material: do I need to import every card component

Tags: angular, angular-material

if I want to use a Material Card components.

```
'mat-card-actions' is not a known element:
'mat-card-content' is not a known element:
'mat-card-title' is not a known element:
'mat-card-header' is not a known element:
'mat-card' is not a known element:
```

do I need to import them one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to import the module, that's it.

```
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for the tree-shaking of Angular.
By the way, you can just create an array in one file and import the array, then spread it into the imports:

```js
FILE 1-- -- -- -- -- -- -
import {
  lib
} from './file'

@NgModule()
export class App {
  ...
  ...
  imports: [
    ...lib
  ]
}



FILE 2-- -- -- -- -- -- -
import { ...
} from '...'

export const lib = [All_Components]
```

Comment: What? No, you just import the module.

Comment: Yeah - no alternativly